# How to list non-unique combinations of two columns with PostGreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

How to list non-unique combinations of two columns?

And get a result like this:

```
col A | col B   | count
foo   | bar     | 3
abc   | hello   | 2
def   | world   | 4
```

If this combination only exists once, then it's not listed:

```
bob   | alice     | 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT col_A, col_B, count(*) AS count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY col_A, col_B
HAVING count(*) > 1
```